# Gradle sync failed: connection time out: consult IDE log for more details

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-2.3

I just installed Android studio 2.3.1, but after starting it is telling me "Grade sync failed: connection time out: connect consult IDE log for more details". Pls I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you look up the IDE's log already? Did you find more details on what went wrong there?

Comment: No I didn't know how to go about it sir please tell me what to do Oliver hader

Comment: I had the same issue, i was using a VPN while building the project. I had to close the VPN to build the project

Answer (score 3):

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
This mean that a file that Gradle has downloaded has become corrupted due to somehow or some reason. This might be the download of Gradle itself (which the wrapper does) or any dependency that Gradle has downloaded to run your build.

Gradle doesn't attempt to detect or resolve the problem, so you need to fix it manually. The solution is often to purge Gradle's download caches and let it get fresh copies of what it needs.

To do that, delete the .gradle directories in both your home directory and in your project's root directory and try building again.

In window home directory of gradle is

C:\Users\User.gradle
In Mac OSX home directory

/Users/User_name/.gradle

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven't figured out this problem yet, it's because you literally have no internet connection which is mandatory for gradle building since the platform checks for potential updates for say, sdk versions, from a server.

However, if you want to build and do your work offline, then go to **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Check Offline work under Global Gradle settings**

Comment: So I can read Stack Overflow with "literally" no internet connection!

Answer (score 1):

With reference to @DaveNOTDavid's answer, i tried this: Go to File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle-> and select "**Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)**". Then sync your project, everything will work fine. But you need an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while downloading the gradle zip from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip. **My issue related to proxy settings, I disabled the proxy & click on Try Again button in build.gradle file.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case i activated antivirus it blocks the downloading gradle files turn of your firewall settings

Answer (score 1):

Click on the SDK Manager and click SDK Tools and check if NDK and CMAKE are checked or not. If they are not checked download and install them. And if the problem persists just try it with a stable internet connection with a fast or a moderate speed. It had happened with me also when I was doing it with mobile phone internet then I tried it with a broadband with fast internet.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a network issue. if you are working using wifi use vpn that would solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

connection timed out:
solution: Just disable your anti-virus for an hour and restart the android studios, in my case my antivirus blocked the connection. while restarting the android studios firewall will ask you the permission, allow it and its all done. The gradle will build successfully

Answer (score 0):

These situations generally occur due to the problem in downloading Gradle components, to overcome this, check your internet proxy and connection properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use some other source internet connection instead of the one you were using while having this error.
 Like I faced the same problem and I disconnected my system from the wifi and connected it to my personal mobile hotspot.
 then go to file->Invalidate Caches/ Restart...  
and your Gradle will build successfully this time.