# Grade project sync failed in android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MILfh.png)[AndroidManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwbk8.png) [new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQwWD.png) [build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MamW.png)
I have tried almost every solution provided on Stack Overflow related to this '**gradle project syc failed**' error, but nothing was useful in my case. I am new to Android Studio and miserably got stuck at the beginning.

In the event log this message appears:

> Gradle sync failed: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>                   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (296ms)

But I am not able to click on (Help | Show Log).

Note: Using Android Studio 3.1.3 and Gradle version 4.9.

[image: the link show a screenshot of error]

Comment: please post your build.gradle and error log

Comment: As @RajshreeTiwari suggested, can you please post your app module's `build.gradle`

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari  screenshot of build.gradle is added to to post.Click on build.gradle in the beginning of my post. where can i find the error log?

Comment: @ashazar screenshot of build.gradle is added to to post.Click on build.gradle in the beginning of my post.

Comment: @VysakhGNair please post your gradle.build ( module app )

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari click on "new",i believe this is what you meant

Comment: @VysakhGNair try this steps and build again : - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620229/2919483

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari Thank you.But unfortunately it still shows the same error.Also i tried deleting .gradle directory.And allowed android studio to download required gadle files.And miserably it still show the same sync failed error.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari I tried to inspect the code and it showed me some error.But i dont know what to do.Screen shot is added to my post.Please Click on "Inspect" in my post

Answer (score 0):

it's probably problem with your plugin implementation

Comment: So what is it to be done?i am a beginner in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have the main class (the one executes when the app starts) that is extended from Application. It will be better to see your `AndroidManifest` as well.

But i guess, if you remove `apply plugin: com.android.application` from `build.gradle` it may work.

Comment: removing " apply plugin: com.android.application " didn't help me.It shows the same error + "Could not find method android() for arguments [build_bn4dguwx3shqdd0xjzcjh7th2$_run_closure1@4c28e7b8] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: AndroidManifest is added to my post.please click on AndroidManifest